# Apps Script - Send Email - Make content in email bold - Format result of Array.toString in bold

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, google-forms, text-formatting, bold

My code sends email notifications every time a Google Form is submitted.  It works, but I want the collected form data as bold in the email.

```
for(var i in headers) 
    message += headers[i] + ': '+ e.namedValues[headers[i]].toString() + "\n\n";  


function sendFormByEmail(e) 
{    
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var headers = s.getRange(1, 1, 1, s.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];    
  var message = "";
  var data = s.getRange(1, 1, 1, s.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
  var subject = "";

  //Get active Spreadsheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  //Get Sheet called 'Form responses 1'
  var fr1 = ss.getSheetByName("Form responses 1");

  //Get all emails from 'Emails' tab
  var emails = ss.getSheetByName("Emails");
  var numRows = emails.getLastRow();
  var emailTo = emails.getRange(2, 2, numRows, 1).getValues();

  // The variable e holds all the form values in an array.
  // Loop through the array and append values to the body.

  for(var i in headers) 
    message += headers[i] + ': '+ e.namedValues[headers[i]].toString() + "\n\n";     

  // Insert variables from the spreadsheet into the subject.
  // In this case, I wanted the part number as part of the
  // email subject. These are the 3rd and 16th columns in my form.
  // This creates an email subject like "Parts Inquiry Submission: 729302"
  subject += e.namedValues[headers[1]].toString();

  // Send the email
  MailApp.sendEmail(emailTo, subject, message); 

  // Based off of a script originally posted by Amit Agarwal - www.labnol.org
  // Credit to Henrique Abreu for fixing the sort order
}
```

Comment: You'd either need to create them inside something like a `<strong>` element, or first create your string and do string.bold(), just depends how you're creating all your DOM elements.

Comment: Your `data` and your `headers` are exactly the same.  You are getting the same range for both.  Shouldn't your data be the last row just added?

Comment: Thank you all for your suggestions.  I ended up getting it work and I've posted the amended code.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you must use the advanced parameter `htmlBody` in the 4th parameter of `sendEmail()` and you need to make the `body` parameter and empty string.

> sendEmail(recipient, subject, body, options)

### Code:

```
message = "<strong>" + message + "</strong>";//Wrap message in bold tags

var options = {
  "htmlBody":message
}

// Send the email
MailApp.sendEmail(emailTo, subject, "",options);//Make email body empty string
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all for your help.  I ended up changing it up a bit.  Here is what I ended up using.

```js
function sendFormByEmail(e) 
{    

  var message = "";
  var subject = ""; 
  var emailTo = "";
  
  //Gets the active Spreadsheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  
  //Get Sheet called 'Form responses 1'
  var fr1 = ss.getSheetByName("Form responses 1");
  var headers = fr1.getRange(1,1,1,fr1.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];  
  
  //Get all emails from 'Emails' tab
  var emails = ss.getSheetByName("Emails");
  var emailTo = emails.getRange(2, 2, emails.getLastRow()-1, 1).getValues().toString();

  // For each column in the spreadsheet, add the column name and it's new entry as a line in the email
  message = "<html>";
  for(var i in headers)
    message += headers[i] + ': <b>'+ e.namedValues[headers[i]].toString() + "</b><br><br>"; 
  message += "</html>";
  
  // Set the subject as the Item Number
  subject = e.namedValues[headers[1]].toString();

  // Send the email
  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: emailTo,
    subject: subject,
    htmlBody: message
  });
  
}
```